# Snackbar not opening in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a basic user registration application in angular. I want to notify the user on successfull creation and if any error is thrown. I am trying to use snackbar to notify the user. However, I am unable to do so. I also inserted an alert to see if I'm going inside that function, and that alert is visible. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my ts Code:

```
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,private userService:UsersService,private router:Router,private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
  addForm: FormGroup;
  selected = 'option2';
  passwordsMatcher = new RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher;

  ngOnInit()
  {

    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password:new FormControl( '',[ Validators.required]),
      passwordAgain: new FormControl('',[ Validators.required]),
      userRole:['',Validators.required],

    },{ validator: RepeatPasswordValidator });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.addForm.valid)
    {
    this.userService.createUser(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
       console.log(data);
       alert("User created");
        //this.router.navigate(['adduser']);
      },error=>
      {console.log(error)
        alert("Usernmame already exists,choose a different userName");
        this.snackBar.open("message", "action", {
          duration: 2000,
        });
        this.addForm.controls.userName.reset();

      });


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The alert was blocking the snackbar. I removed the alert and the snackbar is now visible.